# Insert string into SQL query as plain text in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in SQL Server that checks if search input exists in a column.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product 
WHERE @Type LIKE @SearchResult
```

My problem is that when I fetch `@Type` from user's input, it comes as a string in SQL therefore syntax is wrong and it returns `NULL`.

Is there a way to get rid off single quotations or convert it to plain text in SQL?

So if `@Type` is "ProductName" it would appear in SQL as

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product 
WHERE ProductName LIKE @SearchResult (no single quotes around `ProductName`)
```

Comment: This would require dynamic SQL, but would also be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: That's what I want to avoid so I was wondering if there is a way around it in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use dynamic SQL to replace anything other than a constant in a query:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Product WHERE  @Type LIKE @SearchResult';

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@Type', @Type);

exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@SearchResult NVARCHAR(MAX)',
                   @SearchResult=@SearchResult;
```

You can still pass the `@SearchResult` value using a parameter.

Comment: @koydek You can use `quotename(@Type)` to avoid sql injection if needed.